Updating ScrollView content interferes with ScrollViewReader's scrollTo
I have a ScrollViewReader with a ScrollView inside. Inside my ScrollView I switch over a selectedTab and display a feed of content depending on the tab. When a tab changes, the content of the ScrollView changes, so I want to scroll the user back to the top of the screen. My view looks something like:
ScrollViewReader { reader in
    ScrollView {
        LazyVStack(pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
            EmptyView()
                .id("top")

            Section {
                switch selectedTab {
                    case .profile:
                        ProfileView()
                    case .shop:
                        ShopView()
                    case .favorites:
                        FavoritesView()
                }
            } header: {
                TabControl($selectedTab, onTabUpdate: { _ in
                    reader.scrollTo("top", anchor: .top)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

The problem is, although this mostly works, sometimes the scrollTo seems to bug out and take me to a random scroll offset that is not where EmptyView() is. I've spent hours on this and can't figure out how to ensure the correct behavior.

Did you try to add a small delay (0.01 s) for thz scroll ? This may give time to SwiftUI to recompute the scrollview size before scrolling to top.
